# Why I can´t pass arguments with global action in navigation component?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack

I´m trying to pass an argument with an global action from one destination to another.
I saw this method on the internet but it don´t work for any reasons and I can´t find a solution for it.
I would be thankful for any help.
How I´m trying to pass the argument:

```
epoxyController = EventListEpoxyController { eventClickedID ->
        val navDirections = NavGraphDirections.actionGlobalEventHolder(eventID = eventClickedID)
        findNavController().navigate(navDirections)
```

I added an argument to the eventholder destination in my navgraph and also added an global action.
But for some reasons I can´t find a value for it the word is red and the error is like

> Named arguments are not allowed for non-Kotlin functions
> Cannot find a parameter with this name: eventID
> <
> Thats how my navgraph looks like :

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/eventHolder"
    android:name="de.n.newtest.ui.Fragments.Details.EventHolderKT"
    android:label="fragment_event_holder">
    <argument
        android:name="eventid"
        android:defaultValue="-1"
        app:argType="integer" />
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_global_eventHolder"
    app:destination="@id/eventHolder"
    app:enterAnim="@anim/holderslideinright"
    app:exitAnim="@anim/holderslideoutleft"
    app:popEnterAnim="@anim/holderslideinleft"
    app:popExitAnim="@anim/holderslideoutright">
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val navDirections = NavGraphDirections.actionGlobalEventHolder(eventID = eventClickedID)
```

The `eventID` is created by the IDE to illustrate that this parameter is the callback parameter that points to `eventClickedID`, and it's not supposed to write it yourself as the error implies:

> ```
> Named arguments are not allowed for non-Kotlin functions Cannot find a parameter with this name: eventID < Thats how my navgraph looks like :
> ```

So, you just need to remove it:

```
epoxyController = EventListEpoxyController { eventClickedID ->
        val navDirections = NavGraphDirections.actionGlobalEventHolder(eventClickedID)
        findNavController().navigate(navDirections)
}
```

Comment: While removing the name on the named argument does fix the problem, you didn't mention _why_ the named argument didn't work - the `argName` is `eventid`, not `eventID` - it is just the wrong name.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `android:name="eventid"`. That means that the named parameter for `actionGlobalEventHolder` is `eventid`, not `eventID`.

You'll want to either change your `android:name` to `eventID` or update your code to use `eventid`.

Of course, using a named argument is never a requirement, so you could leave it out entirely.